# DB2 Using max aggregate function

Tags: db2-luw

Can I rewrite this select without using aggregate function to retrieve the highest value

Select *
From A
Where Id= 123
and value =  (
select max(value)
from A inner
where inner.id = 123 )

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that only one record would have the max value, or, if there are ties you don't care which gets returned, then you may use this limit query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE Id = 123
ORDER BY value DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If this doesn't meet your expectations, then stick with your current approach.  Note that you *could* also use `RANK()` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY value DESC) rnk
    FROM A
    WHERE Id = 123
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

But like your version, the above rank query also requires a subquery.

Comment: Ok, the first example matches my approach.
It is better to use `LIMIT 1` or `FETCH FIRST ROWS ONLY`

Comment: `LIMIT 1` is DB2 syntax, while `FETCH FIRST` is ANSI SQL.  I prefer the former as it is more concise.  But the latter (if supported by DB2) would make your SQL code more portable to other databases.

Comment: Db2 for LUW supports both. These queries return different result, if there are multiple rows with the same (id, max(value)) values.